# Excel 2013 filtering on multiple OLAP pivot tables

Tags: vba, excel, olap, olap-cube

VBA newbie here.

While I were able to sync multiple local data pivot tables using one of the VBA codes I found online, I am struggling with the following:

I have 16 OLAP connected pivot tables on one sheet. Each has 6 filters, with 4 being the same across all of them. I'd like to be able to change all pivot tables using one of these four filters.

Answer (score 0):

You could insert a slicer for each of those four fields. Once they are added, you can go to the Slicer Connections and select all of your pivots that are related.

If you are looking for VBA, you would have to loop through all of the pivots on the sheet and then loop through all of the Report Filters members and store the values selected into an array.

Or you could create the slicers on a hidden tab and use the CUBERANKEDMEMBER function to return all of the selections of the slicer and then use that to build your array and apply it to all of your pivot tables when any of your report filters change (you may use a Worksheet_PivotTableAfterValueChange procedure in your worksheet)

Here is how we have done it with 2 pivot tables:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)
''''variables for pivottable changed
    Dim pivotname As String
    Dim pivotname2 As String
    Dim PT As PivotTable
    Dim PT2 As PivotTable

''''variables for pivotrowfields
    Dim pti As PivotItem
    Dim pti2 As PivotField

''''variables for pagefilters
    Dim PF As PivotField
    Dim colPageFields As PivotFields
    Dim aFilters As Variant

'''Un-enable events to avoid an endless loop
    Application.EnableEvents = False

'''Set variables
    pivotname = Target.Name

    If pivotname = "PivotTable1" Then
        pivotname2 = "PivotTable4"
    Else
        pivotname2 = "PivotTable1"
        pivotname = "PivotTable4"
    End If

    If ActiveSheet.Name = "Slicer Setup" Then
        Sheets("By Org Structure").Activate
    End If

    Set PT = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("" & pivotname & "")
    Set PT2 = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("" & pivotname2 & "")

    Set colPageFields = PT.PageFields

'''action for changing the filters on Page Fields
    For Each PF In colPageFields

                    PF.CubeField.EnableMultiplePageItems = True
                    'PT2.PivotFields(PF.Name).CubeField.EnableMultiplePageItems = True
                    aFilters = PT.PivotFields(PF.Name).VisibleItemsList
                    If aFilters(1) = "" Then
                        If PT.PivotFields(PF.Name).CubeField.AllItemsVisible = True Then
                            PT2.PivotFields(PF.Name).ClearAllFilters
                        Else
                            PT2.PivotFields(PF.Name).VisibleItemsList = Array("")
                        End If
                    Else
                        PT2.PivotFields(PF.Name).VisibleItemsList = Array(aFilters)
                    End If

    Next

Set colPageFields = PT.RowFields

'''action for changing the filters on Row Fields
    For Each PF In colPageFields
                     PF.CubeField.EnableMultiplePageItems = True
                    'PT2.PivotFields(PF.Name).CubeField.EnableMultiplePageItems = True
                    aFilters = PT.PivotFields(PF.Name).VisibleItemsList
                    If aFilters(1) = "" Then
                        If PT.PivotFields(PF.Name).CubeField.AllItemsVisible = True Then
                            PT2.PivotFields(PF.Name).ClearAllFilters
                        Else
                            PT2.PivotFields(PF.Name).VisibleItemsList = Array("")
                        End If
                    Else
                        PT2.PivotFields(PF.Name).VisibleItemsList = Array(aFilters)
                    End If
    Next


'''Re-enable events to allow for this event macro to be kicked off again next time pivottables are changed
    Application.EnableEvents = True

    ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Seems that I cannot link the slicer as the Pivot Table has grouped fields and is based on OLAP.   Am I correct to assume that I need to Dim all PivotTables I have and replicate code for them when adjusting your VBA code?

Comment: It world probably be cleaner and shorter to loop through the pivots with a for or  for each loop.